# SOQL Optimization to reduce time consuming to execute query with OR Filter Condition

Tags: soql

Please Suggest the approaches or help in optimizing the Logic/ Query to reduce time Consuming in executing the Order Object Query ( which is taking 10 minutes), this is effecting user experience

```
//ListMethod

public list<orders__c> getstart() {
    Map<Id,UserTerritory> UserTerritoryCurrentUserMap = new  Map<Id,UserTerritory>([Select u.UserId, u.TerritoryId, u.IsActive, u.Id  From UserTerritory u Where u.isActive=true and u.userId =: UserInfo.getUserId()]);
    system.debug('-----UserTerritoryCurrentUserMap SIZE-------'+UserTerritoryCurrentUserMap.size());

    set<Id> TerritoryIdSet = new set<Id>();
    for(UserTerritory ut:UserTerritoryCurrentUserMap.values())
    {
          TerritoryIdSet.add(ut.TerritoryId);
    }    

    List<Territory> childTerritories = [Select Id from Territory where ParentTerritoryID in :TerritoryIdSet];

    for(Territory ct : childTerritories) {
         TerritoryIdSet.add(ct.Id);
    }

    system.debug('-----TerritoryIdSet -------'+TerritoryIdSet);
    system.debug('-----TerritoryIdSet SIZE-------'+TerritoryIdSet.size());

    list<Group> map_group = [Select Id, RelatedId from Group where (Type='Territory' OR Type='TerritoryAndSubordinates') AND RelatedId IN : TerritoryIdSet];
    system.debug('-----map_group -------'+map_group);

    Set<String> tempList = new Set<String>();

    for(My_Custom_Object__c s : [SELECT Legacy_Field__c , Account__c FROM My_Custom_Object__c WHERE Account__c IN (Select  AccountId FROM AccountShare where ( UserOrGroupId IN : map_group OR  UserOrGroupId =:UserInfo.getUserId()) AND RowCause IN ('Territory', 'TerritoryManual', 'TerritoryRule')) ]) {
        tempList.add(s.Legacy_Field__c);
    }

    system.debug('-----tempList-------'+tempList);
    system.debug('-----tempList-------'+tempList.size()); 

    List<orders__c> orders =[SELECT id, Name, Orders__c, Bill_to__c, Payer__c, Ship_To__c, Sold_to__c FROM orders__c WHERE Bill_to__c IN: tempList OR Payer__c IN: tempList OR Ship_To__c IN: tempList OR Sold_to__c IN: tempList];                                     
    system.debug('-----orders-------'+orders);

    return orders;

}
```

How to Optimize below Query

```
 List<orders__c> orders =[SELECT id, Name, Orders__c, Bill_to__c, 
 Payer__c, Ship_To__c, Sold_to__c FROM orders__c WHERE Bill_to__c IN: 
 tempList OR Payer__c IN: tempList OR Ship_To__c IN: tempList OR  
 Sold_to__c IN: tempList]; 

 system.debug('-----orders-------'+orders);
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting point would be to consider filtering records based on CreatedDate, Status etc. Try to find any fields on your object that will eliminate records from the logic and include them in your query. Also if you're dealing with historical data, you might want to start thinking about an archiving approach (possibly a batch to mark Archived__c on old records) which then you can also include in your SOQL query to narrow down the number of records returned.

There is no definitive answer to this since we can't see your data model and amount of data you're dealing with.

Another good thing that you could do is start reading some documentation on optimising SOQL, which can give you more ideas and perhaps a different approach to handle your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is the query you posted at end is the one taking more time or the full code time complexity is 10 mins as you said.

And can you revisit your data model and try make some lookup relationship between objects as I can see you are querying many object in one executions which could be related using lookup like UserTerritory,Territory objects.